# Why System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException is thrown instead of System.UriFormatException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, throw

I have a simple Class with 1 property and validation on set.
I expect `System.UriFormatException` to be thrown, but `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` is thrown on invalid uri.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _baseUrl;

    public string BaseUrl
    {
        get => _baseUrl;

        set
        {
            if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(value, UriKind.Absolute))
            {
                throw new UriFormatException($"Host is not valid Uri: {BaseUrl}");
            }

            _baseUrl = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change this class so it looks like as is below and I call `Validate()` on the object I have created, then I have `System.UriFormatException` thrown, why is there this difference. Ideally, I would like to throw `System.UriFormatException` with the first snippet. I have a feeling that is caused because is thrown during object instantiation but would like to know more about it.

```
public class MyClass {

public string BaseUrl { get; set; }

public void Validate () {
    if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString (BaseUrl, UriKind.Absolute)) {
        throw new UriFormatException ($"Host is not valid Uri: {BaseUrl}");
    }
  }
}
```

I am changing the code, so that exception is thrown during instantiation of the object, and not later with `Validate()`. That allows me to save few lines, and also the fact that `Validate()` maybe forgotten to be called. Also, I am aware of `ValidationAttribute` class and I am not interested in it.

Comment: In the first case, how are you calling the setter?  Normally you see a `TargetInvocationException` when you call something via Reflection and the target of the refelction `Invoke` call throws an exception: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception

Comment: Please show the usage of MyClass. Without it, the described behavior is not reproduceable.

Comment: You are right @Flydog57. When I call `var myClass = new MyClass { BaseUrl = "invalidUrl" }` then `UriFormatException` is thrown. In my tests, `MyClass` is tested indirectly in integration tests, and its values are populated using `IConfigurationSection.Bind(myClass)`. Since I was not aware of `TargetInvocationException ` I was expecting the same exception with different implementation not having to change the tests. Thanks, learned something new!

Comment: I think the original exception should be in the `InnerException` property of the `TargetInvocationException`, so you can tell what happened

Comment: That is correct, the inner exception includes the original exception.